# v-for with axios mysql in page.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I'm new with Vue2... I have a 3840x2160 grid, in an offline.vue template page [this is my project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf4xg.png)

I have to populate the grid with images taken from a mysql database with an axios.post.

```
    <div id="mybanner" class="adGrid" style="background-image: url('/img/grid.svg');">
        
    <a href="https://yourdomain.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://yourimage.png" title="Your title" style="left: 1500px; top: 0px; width: 10px; height: 10px; position:absolute;">
        </a>
    
    ...
    
    <a href="https://yourdomain.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://yourimage.png" title="Your title" style="left: 1500px; top: 0px; width: 10px; height: 10px; position:absolute;">
        </a>
    
     </div>
```

from the Post i get the following array:

```
{idx: "58", height: "10", width: "10"​​, x: "1500", ​​y: "0", image: "https://yourimage.png", link: "https://yourdomain.com", title: "your title​​"}
```

how can i write v-for function?

for something like:

```
<a v-for="image in images" :href="image.link">
<img :src="image.image" :title="image.title" :style="left:${image.x}px; top:${image.y}px; width:${image.width}px; height:${image.height}px; position:absolute;">
</a>
```

how can I write the script ?

Comment: The array you have posted is an Object... Is your array an array of Objects that looks like that or?

Comment: like this ```:style="`left:${image.x}px; top:${image.y}px`" :src="image.image" :title="image.title" ``` don't forget binding the attributes by ":"